# Manage wordpress files in google container Engine and kubernetes

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, sftp, google-kubernetes-engine

I am in the middle of no where. Following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk

I deployed wordpress to google container engine. Now i have no idea how to access wordpress files on this Persistent Disks either with ftp or sftp. I can access project files with sftp on filezilla but can't find wordpress core files in it. Is there any way i can access these wordpress files?

Answer (score 1):

The persistent disk containing the wordpress files are attached to the wordpress pod. This disk is mounted on /var/www/html folder under the wordpress pod. You can access these files by connecting to the wordpress pod. First get the name of the running pod by executing the following command,

```
 kubectl get pods
```

Now use the name of the wordpress pod in the following command. This runs a remote shell on the wordpress pod,

```
kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> sh
```

In the shell, run the ls command to see the list of wordpress files,

```
# ls
```

This will list the wordpress files. If you want to edit these files, you need to install vim or nano.

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install vim
# apt-get install nano
# vi wp-config.php
```

Note that the vim/nano will be removed if the wordpress pod is restarted. If you really want them inside your pod, you will need to create a custom container.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011597/1197205
This plugin uses Google Cloud Storage so it's easy to access via the UI

Another solution (only if you run 1 pod because otherwise you'd need to sync between disks): use an sftp container as a sidecar for the wordpress pod

Comment: Can you please explain the second solution. I now have 2 pods following this https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk. Creating new cluster in container you mean? I can not connect cluster to sftp as it has no ip. I can connect an instance created by cluster's loadbalancer to sftp but there i can not file wordpress files.

Comment: pod can be 1 or more containers, the containers in the same pod are in the same namespace hence they each can access each other's filesystem and network.