# Update ConfigMap mounted to a Pod by updating the mounted data

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

I want to update the data in a ConfigMap logically inside a Pod by mounting the ConfigMap as a volume dir and changes made in the dir files should update the ConfigMap accordingly. Is it achievable ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Kubernete's ConfigMaps Writable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046908/are-kubernetes-configmaps-writable)

Comment: If you need to modify this file you need to mount as a volumeMount. Is it really needed to be a configMap, or could be a writeable volume in the pod ?