# Flink kubernetes deployment - how to provide S3 credentials from Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I'm trying to deploy a Flink stream processor to a Kubernetes cluster with the help of the official [Flink kubernetes operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-stable/).
The Flink app also uses Minio as its state backend. Everything worked fine until I tried to provide the credentials from Hashicorp Vault in the following way:

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: flink-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceAccount: sa-example
  podTemplate:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: pod-template
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: default:sa-example
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
      # ....
  flinkVersion: v1_14
  flinkConfiguration:
    presto.s3.endpoint: https://s3-example-api.dev.net
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.storageDir: s3p://example-flink/example-1/high-availability/
    high-availability.cluster-id: example-1
    high-availability.namespace: example
    high-availability.service-account: default:sa-example
#    presto.s3.access-key: *
#    presto.s3.secret-key: *  
    presto.s3.path-style-access: "true"
    web.upload.dir: /opt/flink
  jobManager:
    podTemplate:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: job-manager-pod-template
        annotations:
          vault.hashicorp.com/namespace: "/example/dev"
          vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
          vault.hashicorp.com/agent-init-first: "true"
          vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-appsecrets.yaml: "example/Minio"
          vault.hashicorp.com/role: "example-serviceaccount"
          vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: auth/example
          vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-appsecrets.yaml: |
            {{- with secret "example/Minio" -}}
            presto.s3.access-key: {{.Data.data.accessKey}}
            presto.s3.secret-key: {{.Data.data.secretKey}}
            {{- end }}
```

When I comment the `presto.s3.access-key` and `presto.s3.secret-key` config values in the flinkConfiguration, replace them with the above listed `Hashicorp Vault` annotations and try to provide them programmatically during runtime:

```scala
val configuration: Configuration = getSecretsFromFile("/vault/secrets/appsecrets.yaml")

val env = org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(configuration)
```

I receive the following error message:

*java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@5331f738: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@bc0353f: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem$PrestoS3OutputStream.uploadObject(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:1278) ~[flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem$PrestoS3OutputStream.close(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:1226) ~[flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72) ~[flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:101) ~[flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.common.HadoopDataOutputStream.close(HadoopDataOutputStream.java:52) ~[flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:80) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:72) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobUtils.moveTempFileToStore(BlobUtils.java:385) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer.moveTempFileToStore(BlobServer.java:680) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.put(BlobServerConnection.java:350) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.run(BlobServerConnection.java:110) [flink-dist_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]*

I initially also tried to append the secrets to flink-config.yaml in the docker-entrypoint.sh based on this [documentation - Configure Access Credentials](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials):

```
if [ -f '/vault/secrets/appsecrets.yaml' ]; then
  (echo && cat '/vault/secrets/appsecrets.yaml') >> $FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml
fi
```

The question is how to provide the S3 credentials during the runtime since the Flink operator mounts the **flink-config.yaml** from a config map and it is a flink-conf.yaml: **Read-only file system**.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this from the Kubernetes operator. In fact, this is not a limitation of the Flink Kubernetes operator, it is due to the fact of lack in support in Kubernetes native integration. There is a separate story for this in the Kubernetes operator side - [FLINK-27491](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27491).

As a workaround, what you can do is, set up an init container and update the config map from the init container using kubernetes API after reading it from the vault. So the updated config map should have the secrets replaced by the init container and those will be visible to the job manager and all of its task managers. The whole Flink cluster journey starts only after updating the config map from the init container so it should be visible to the Flink cluster.

A simple example to update the config map from the init container can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046908/are-kubernetes-configmaps-writable#answer-71662405). In this example, the config map is updated with a simple CURL command. In theory, you can use any lightweight client to update the config map like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/).

A side note: If possible I would suggest to use AWS IAM role rather than IAM plain secrets as IAM role is more secure compared to IAM static credentials.

Comment: Hi Jaya, I wanted to avoid exposing the secret via a config map, that will not pass the review during Pull Request etc. Thx

Comment: @Kubus Not able to get exactly why that would not pass PR. The above approach that I mentioned will not end up committing the secret to version control. Only you need to add the key of the vault to the version control. The init container get input as a list of vault keys, then it needs to talk to the vault using API to retrieve those secret and appends those secret value to the config map in the runtime dynamically. The link that I attached in the example, should show what it would like. At the moment, due to lack dynamic variable resolving feature, this is the option that community suggested.