# copy PODIP in configmap during kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, configmap

I need to pass "PODIP" env value to configmap for configuration during k8s deployment

deploy.yaml

```
- env:
  - name: PODIP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
```

how to do this? 10x

Comment: this is an environment variable from a fieldRef and fieldPath. You don't need a configMap in this case.

Comment: I want to see during the deploy in configmap.yaml something like that: mypodip: $POPIP. how can I show the value?

Comment: configmap is a static file without environment values

Comment: Consider what would happen if you had multiple pods trying to use the same ConfigMap (multiple replicas of the same Deployment, or even multiple different Deployments).  The Pod only reads the ConfigMap and never writes back to it.

Answer (score 1):

I did small research on topic and it come out that a configmap was **intentionally** made [ReadOnly](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099) some time ago.

If you really need interacting with files from a configmap then you could instead put the files in a writeable volume and  [mount the volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681206/what-would-be-an-ideal-way-to-share-writable-volume-across-containers-for-a-web). 
Or you could to use the centralized configuration like consul.

Addtionally, you can try storing values in a database. Another option to store configuration information could be a distributed cache  [such as redis](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-4-service-discovery-and-configuration/5-4-1-using-redis-to-store-configuration-information/) or hazelcast, etc.

That is [Pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60258/files)  which made ConfigMaps ReadOnly.

Hope that helps.
Let me know if that was the info you've been looking for :)